# 'Leave this page' message display twice on IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have these line of code using onbeforeunload to ask user to save their data before closing the page. The code works well in Firefox & Chrome.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (isUpdated) return "You have unsaved data";
    else return undefined;
};
```

[image]

In IE (10), when I chose "Leave this page", everything's fine. But when I chose "Stay on this page", the popup closed and then display again, right after that, I have to click one more time on "Stay on this page", which I find annoying.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: best solution....remove `onbeforeunload`....even once is annoying

Comment: I wish I could just do that, this is a requirement...

Comment: Are you hitting the browser [x] button to close the window, or clicking on a <a href> tag to navigate away?

Comment: @halfnibble I use a link to navigate to other page

Comment: Next question. Is the page change suppose to happen via a JavaScript onclick() event, or via a traditional link? For example: <a href="/newpage.html">New Page</a>

I've read somewhere that IE10 treats clicking an <a> tag as a requirement to fire the "onbeforeunload" event even if the <a> tag is suppose to fire an onclick event instead of load a new page.

Comment: @halfnibble The problem seems to occur only when I click on an onclick event of a list item `li`. I have onlcick event for in button also but the message only appear once. Thanks to you I have more clue to research, but haven't found any solution ...

Answer (score -2):

Add the `onbeforeunload` event handler to `window.href` instead of `window`:

```
window.href.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (isUpdated) {
        return "You have unsaved data";
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unable to set property 'onbeforeunload' of undefined or null reference.