# IE 11 - Leave this Page / Stay on this Page Popup Comes Twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, redirect, jquery-events

This is happening only in IE.
I have a page with a Close button. On clicking on the Close button with any changes to the page, I am getting the "Leave or stay on this page" popup. Clicking Leave button is working as expected, but on clicking Stay button, the popup closes and immediately loads again. On clicking Stay for the second time closes the popup and everything is normal. How can I make the popup up come only once on clicking Close button with some unsaved changes?
Also, after clicking Close for the second time, I see some unexpected error in IE debugger.

**Note - Stay button click is working as expected if refresh page or click on other page links. Issue is only during clicking on the Close button.**

Below is the event handler of Close button.

```
this._$el.find('#closeButton').on('click', function () {
   document.location = "http://localhost:7001/myLocation";
});
```

**HTML for Close button:**

```
<button title="Close" class="btn" id="closeButton" type="button">Close</button>
```

**IE version :** 11.0.9600.18537CO

**Unexpected error in IE debugger:**
[image: Unexpected error in IE debugger]

I found this discussion also, but it seems different. Please let me know if there is any connection.
['Leave this page' message display twice on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757136/leave-this-page-message-display-twice-on-ie10)

Comment: Have you tried using preventDefault() ?

Comment: Yes. But it did not help!

Comment: can you please add the code for "leave/stay" also.

Answer (score 0):

The IE error is because:

`document.location` in IE is read-only.

Try using:

`window.location` instead.

Please post code for the "stay/leave" functionality.